# Как расшифровать api приложения на андроиде для парсера?

Tags: java, android, парсер

очу написать парсер, но парсинг сайта требует селениум, а брать запросы апи через приложение на андроиде я не умею.

Как можно подсмотреть апи в приложении? Достаточно ли открыть через Apktool приложуху и походить по коду, или может ваершарк какой-то поставить и посмотреть урлы, которые, вероятно, будут по https?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть apk файл наиболее вероятно в нем будет использоваться обфускация кода (запутывание), что делает невозможным изучить код приложения. (Неопытные разработчики иногда отключают эту функцию). О работе запросов по https ничего не знаю, извините.